# Recursively edit multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array containing some text strings that need modifying. My initial thought was to iterate over it recursively and make the edits, but I've realised that calling the function internally must be breaking the referencing, and I can't see a way around this.

```
function mysqlifyArray($array)
  {
      global $connection;
      foreach ($array as &$item)
      {
          if (is_string($item))
          {
              echo $item;
              $item = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $item);
              echo $item.'<br>';
          }
          elseif (is_array($item))
          {
              $item = mysqlifyArray($item);
          }
      }
      unset($item);
      return $array;
  }
```

Comment: why recursive instead of just loops over each dimension?

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen because the number of dimensions could vary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Set reference in your function declaration](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

```
function mysqlifyArray(&$array)
{
    // ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use the built-in [`array_walk_recursive()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)

```
function mysqlify(&$value, $index) {
    global $connection;
    return $value = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $value);
}

function mysqlify_array(&$array) {
    return array_walk_recursive($array, 'mysqlify');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

```
function mysqlifyArray($array)
{
    global $connection;
    foreach ($array as $item)
    {
        if (is_string($item)) {
            echo $item;
            $item = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $item);
            echo $item.'<br>';
        } else if (is_array($item)) {
            $item = mysqlifyArray($item);
        }

        unset($item);
    }

    return $array;
}
```

Note: I am not sure why you used reference for $item variable, instead you can use the reference variable in the method.

Comment: I think reference passing is deprecated in 5.3.0 and removed from 5.4.0.

Comment: @copper.hat You got any ref to support that?

Comment: @swordofpain: Look at the first note in http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php.

Comment: @copper.hat That's not the same thing. It says that you'll get an error if you try to force the reference *at call time* (i.e. when *calling* the function, e.g. `$b = my_func(&$a)`). It also says that declaring the ref *at definition time* is enough (i.e. when *declaring* the function, e.g. `function my_func(&$a) { ... }`). I suppose PHP devs are cleaning their codebase a bit and removed some edge cases where you needed both def-time and call-time references for the mechanism to work.

Comment: @swordofpain: The OP edited the answer, previously there was line of the form "$item = mysqlifyArray(&$item);" which is what my comment referred to. I should have been a little more explicit about what I was referring to.